How to use query parameters on expanded properties of application objects with MS Graph?
I'm experiencing with query parameters to specify and control the amount of data returned in a response.
More specifically, I'm trying to limit the expanded owner information for applications:

Directory objects that are owners of the application. Read-only.
Nullable. Supports $expand, $filter (/$count eq 0, /$count ne 0,
/$count eq 1, /$count ne 1), and $select nested in $expand.

The following request returns full owner information, not just their IDs.
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications?$filter=displayName eq 'api-lab'&$expand=owners($select=id)&$count=true

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/application?view=graph-rest-1.0#relationships
How can I make it only return the IDs of owners?
Furthermore, how would I use $filter on owners?
If I try to filter on the owners, I get the following error:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications?$filter=displayName eq 'api-lab'&$expand=owners&$filter=owners/$count eq 0&$count=true

{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
        "message": "Property 'owners' does not exist as a declared property or extension property.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2024-07-07T12:12:14",
            "request-id": "e4795a2b-4602-44d7-88df-13ae2d47fccb",
            "client-request-id": "888d1473-7351-636d-5033-bbb493aae52e"
        }
    }
}

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

According to this request the Microsoft Graph API doesn't support nested filtering. You can get the expanded data and then write the code to filter it locally by yourself.

But it should support "$select nested in $expand." according to the docs. Can you get that to work?

Your query to return only owners ids is correct, but for some reason it's not working. What will work is this workaround. Adding $select will trigger the inner $select inside the $expand
GET /v1.0/applications?$filter=displayName eq 'api-lab'&$expand=owners($select=id)&$select=id,displayName

To be able to filter applications without owners (what you have tried), you need to add request header ConsistencyLevel with the value eventual
GET /v1.0/applications?$filter=displayName eq 'api-lab' and owners/$count eq 0&$count=true
ConsistencyLevel: eventual

Don't use expand in this case

Why does the outer $select trigger the inner one?

Why are you able to reference owners in the query, when you're not expanding it? How do you know this is an advanced query (ConsistencyLevel: eventual)?

Do you know how to return applications with one or more passwordCredentials (client secrets)? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/application?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties

$select -> I guess it's some kind of bug in the Graph API on the server side. I've realized the same behavior for another endpoints some time ago.
About owners -> There is a similar example in the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-5-get-applications-with-less-than-two-owners. If I check for apps without owners, it doesn't make sense to expand owners (it will be empty)

$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications?`$filter=startswith(displayName, 'wb-xxxx')&`$select=displayName,createdDateTime&`$expand=Owners(`$select=displayName, id)"

$headers = @{
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
    "Authorization" = "Bearer " + $token.access_token
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri -Headers $headers

$response | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10

$response

output:
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#applications(displayName,createdDateTime,owners(displayName,id))",
  "value": [
    {
      "displayName": "wb-xxxxx",
      "createdDateTime": "2023-07-06T07:08:13Z",
      "id": "bf428da1-469f-4b9f-xxxxx",
      "owners": [
        {
          "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
          "displayName": "wenbo1",
          "id": "5cf44736-4eaa-4482-xxxxx"
        },
        {
          "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
          "displayName": "wenbo2",
          "id": "492b05b3-bc6c-4497-xxxxx"
        },
        {
          "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
          "displayName": "wenbo3",
          "id": "b9c17778-5c87-4ff0-xxxx"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}


Thank you. You're also using an outer $select to make the inner one work? Why do you use backticks (`) in the URL?

In powershell script without (`) such as using $filter instead of `$filter, will treate $filter as a variable but actually we need it to be the query symbol

I don't think you query work without outer $select. Can you say why? :)

First $select shows the outer properties and the second $select shows the properties in owners object. the two are not related.
